# Не могу совладать с pytube и os на python

Tags: python, ос, pytube

В общем-то с помощью библиотеки pytube сделал загрузчик видео с ютуба, но хотелось бы всегда быть в курсе, идет ли загрузка, или нет, поэтому написал такой код

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os

yt = YouTube(input())
    
streams = yt.streams

my_video = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True).desc().first()

my_video.download()

chec = yt.title
tile = os.path.exists(f"Trash/{chec}.mp4")

if tile == "True":
    print("Download Started!") 
else:
    print("Something wrong...")
```

В прошлом частенько замечал что как только начинается загрузка, в проводнике уже существует файл загрузки, пусть и не рабочий, но все же существует, не совсем понимаю почему, но каждый раз у меня выводится *Something wrong...*

Comment: А файл точно есть? Может нужно чуть подождать пока он появится,  вы проверяете раньше, чем файл появляется?

Comment: Только что проверил, файл появляется в процессе работы скрипта

Answer (score 1):

`"True"` - это строка. `True != "True"`.

Проверка булевой переменной на истину делается либо `if tile:` либо `if tile is True:` (прошу заметить, без кавычек).

Comment: Спасибо, но к сожалению не помогло, по прежнему Something wrong

Comment: Вот вы запускаете скрипт из папки, а относительно этой папки по пути `Trash/{chec}.mp4` файл действительно есть? Нигде в коде не написано, что файл должен попасть в папку `Trash`, [согласно документации](https://pytube.io/en/latest/api.html#pytube.Stream.download) надо было бы написать `output_path='Trash'`, разве нет?

Comment: Все видео загружаются в папку trash, проверял неоднократно, а загружаются именно туда по одной простой причине, скрипт лежит в этой папке

Comment: Ну тогда оставить `tile = os.path.exists(f"{chec}.mp4")` пробовали? Если скрипт находится в папке `<project_root>/Trash` и запуск происходит прямо из этой же папки, то вы изначальным кодом в вопросе проверяете `<project_root>/Trash/Trash`, а у вас не то что файлов в папке нет... самой папки поди нет. Звучит логично?

Comment: Вполне, сейчас попробую указать полный путь Upd: результат к сожалению тот же